# Any good Wizard libraries in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, mxml, wizard

I'm looking for a good "Wizard" library in Flex before rolling my own. The important features are:

- Multiple custom input panels in sequence.
- Ability to prepopulate the data fields using an object, *but* cancelling at any point leaves original data unmodified.
- Ability to move to back and forth in panel sequence without losing data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is something I wrote that might fit your needs

http://code.google.com/p/flashmatticomponents/wiki/Wizard

Hope it helps,
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest just using a ViewStack container; alongside this I suggest using ViewStack effects to transition between each "input panel": http://www.efflex.org/

A "input panel" would probably be made up of a TitleWindow component (with the closeButton=true) and a Form component (with TextInputs,ComboBoxes,DateSelectors,etc)

Unfortunately, I have not come upon any library with this functionality.